# What's the actual downside of storing functions / components on Redux?

Tags: redux

I would like to store a function / component inside the Redux state to pass it to another part of the application.

I've read that this is not recommended, but what exactly will happen?

- Will it affect the performance of other data stored on Redux to the point it becomes visibly slow to the user?
- Will it cause components that depend on this component or any data stored on Redux to continuously re-render causing the app to slow to a crawl?
- Will Redux just break randomly all the time?

What are the actual, practical downsides to doing this, putting aside the intentions behind the creation of the library?

Comment: Did you mean putting functions / component inside the redux state ?

Comment: @julien-kode Yes. I've reworded it to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks I've created an answer that might help you and other people that face the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/73057253/7618742

Comment: Let me know if you want help to clarify more

Comment: You want to inject your components to get them at another place in the app tree ?

Comment: @julien-kode Yes, and it does seem to work, from what little testing I've done.

Comment: Maybe for your case you can just create a custom react provider and provide it, to make it different from redux store who contains app logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to just store the component I needed on Redux and haven't seen any downsides, which led me to believe there is no real issue in doing this, as long as you don't care about serialization.

Answer (score 0):

## Do not put functions or components (non-serializable value) in redux state or actions

Avoid putting non-serializable this can break the following things:

- debugging
- server side rendering
- state persistence
- and more, this can create performance issue

This is described more in depth [here in the official documentation](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions)

Comment: What do you mean by "state persistence" and how will it actually affect my application? The other two are non-issues to me, although I'm curious how would this affect SSR.

Comment: When you are using SSR with Next.js for example, state is usually send in the props as a json. You cannot serialise function into a json

Comment: So, as long as I only pass components in the browser, I should be ok, right? But what about the "state persistence" and "performance" issue, what do they entail, both if used heavily or just once per route load?

Comment: If you want to persit your state inside local storage same issue as SSR because function are non serialisable

Comment: For the performance I think it depends on a lot of parameters, your number of render, how frequently you update the state etc... 

I guess you can still use a selector from reselect to memoize the return to avoid perf impact 

But I do not recommend you to do that at all, just for the separation of concern maybe you can create a provider dedicated to component injection

Comment: Context is made for dependency injection, you seems to just need dependency injection in your case for your component. And can keep redux for your business logic

Comment: Oh, so "state persistence" meant LS. I'm not using that, so that's okay. As for the performance, will it trigger too many re-renders without need or affect other data?

Comment: I don't really want to use Context since I want to be able to set this value from outside components and to keep the pattern of Redux being global storage and Context being a replacement to prop-drilling only.

Comment: You can use context + hooks to do that

Comment: I understand that you want to keep your current setup to do this instead of creating a new one

Comment: But there doesn't seem to be an actual downside in using Redux while there are upsides (dispatch outside components / not needing an ancestor component to know about them, except for ReduxProvider).

Comment: If storing it there won't trigger extra re-renders or performance issues, it seems to me there is no real reason to not use it in this context.